# Why does the method using the Green's function for $\nabla^2 \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = \delta(x)\delta(y)$ not work?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, physics, dirac-delta

I have the Poisson Equation (with $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$) with the following form:
$$\nabla^2 \Phi (\mathbf{x}) = \delta(x)\delta(y)$$
I used 2 methods for the resolution of this PDE. I am frustated, I don't know why the first method doesn't work.

---

**This method doesn't work:**
I know that the solution is:

$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{V} \frac{\delta(x')\delta(y')}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}\,dV'$$

Where $V$ is a cylinder with $z$-axis as the axis of the cylinder between  $z'=\pm l$, $2l$ is an arbitrary length with the condition $|z|\ll l$. The Green's function of 3-D Laplacian $\nabla^2$ is $G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x'})=-\dfrac{1}{4\pi|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'}|}$. So:

$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-l}^{l} \left[(z'-z)^2 + \rho^2\right]^{-1/2}\,dz',\quad \rho=x^2+y^2$$

With $\rho$ the cylindrical radius. Using the substitution $z'-z=\rho\tan\phi$ and $dz'=\rho\sec^2\phi\,d\phi$:

$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\arctan(l+z/\rho)}^{\arctan(l-z/\rho)} \left[\rho^2\tan^2\phi + \rho^2\right]^{-1/2}\rho\sec^2\phi\,d\phi$$
With the identity $\tan^2\phi+1=\sec^2\phi$ :
$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{-\arctan(l+z/\rho)}^{\arctan(l-z/\rho)} \sec\phi\,d\phi$$
$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\Big[\ln|\tan\phi+\sec\phi|\Big]_{-\arctan(l+z/\rho)}^{\arctan(l-z/\rho)}$$

$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\left|\frac{ \frac{l-z}{\rho} + \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{l-z}{\rho}\right)^2} }{ -\frac{l+z}{\rho} + \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{l+z}{\rho}\right)^2} }\right|$$

$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\left|\frac{ 1-\frac{z}{l} + \sqrt{\frac{\rho^2}{l^2} + \left(1-\frac{z}{l}\right)^2 } }{ -1-\frac{z}{l} + \sqrt{\frac{\rho^2}{l^2} + \left(1+\frac{z}{l}\right)^2 } }\right|$$

If I send $l\to \infty$:

$$ \Phi(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\left|\frac{2}{0}\right|=-\infty$$
This is not a satisfactory answer. Why does this not work?.

---

**This method works**: If $\mathbf{E}=\nabla\Phi$, then the equation is like Gauss law:

$$ \nabla\cdot \mathbf{E} = \delta(x)\delta(y) $$
$$ \int_{V} \nabla\cdot \mathbf{E} \,dV' = \int_{V} \delta(x')\delta(y') dV' $$
Where $V$ is a cylinder of lenght $L$, radius $\rho$ with $z$-axis as the axis of the cylinder. So: 
$$ \int_{V} \nabla\cdot \mathbf{E} \,dV' = L $$
With the Gauss theorem:
$$ \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{A'} = L $$
With cylindrical symetry arguments we can say that $\mathbf{E}=E(\rho)\hat{\rho}$ doesn't depends of $z$, so:
$$ E(\rho)2\pi\rho L= L $$
$$ E(\rho) = \frac{1}{2\pi\rho}$$
$$ \mathbf{E} = \frac{1}{2\pi\rho}\hat{\rho}$$
This implies:
$$ \Phi(\rho) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\left(\frac{\rho}{R}\right)$$

With $R$ as a constant. This is the Green's function for 2-D Laplacian $\nabla^2$ and it is correct.

Comment: Right at the start you already wrote an integral which doesn't converge, as a result of the infinite amount of charge on the axis. In the second case you regularize matters by thinking of a finite charged line and then send the length to infinity.

Comment: @Ian but if I work the integral with finite limits of integration, this result will be the solution of a finite amount of charge on the axis with a given length. Then, I can send this arbitrary length to infinity and the problem is the same.

Comment: But now look at what happens when you solve for $\nabla \Phi$ on the finite cylinder: the $L$'s cancel and you recover something scale invariant. If you sent $L \to \infty$ immediately this wouldn't work, you would just get $\infty=\infty$.

Comment: @Ian I don't know how does the scale invariant work , but do you say that it is impossible the first method in this case?

Comment: You can't do the first thing directly because it relies on the assumption that the right side is a compactly supported distribution, which the infinite line of charge is not. But you can do it for a truncation, like a line segment of charge, and then make the line arbitrarily long, say for $z \in [-L/2,L/2]$, and examine the resulting potential where $|z| \ll L$.

Comment: @Ian I edited the post with your stage direction, and the result is the same.

Comment: So now when you send $l \to \infty$, simply replacing $\rho/l$ by $0$ isn't what you want, because this physically corresponds to going all the way to the line. Instead in the denominator you have the expansion $\sqrt{(\rho/l)^2+(1+z/l)^2}=(1+z/l)+\frac{(\rho/l)^2}{2(1+z/l)}$ which after including it in the rest of the denominator gives $\frac{(\rho/l)^2}{2}$ which seems to be the desired result.

Comment: If you set $z=0$ at the start,  by symmetry the answer should be twice the integral from $0$ to $l$.  this integral is $$-\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\left| \frac{l}{\rho} + \sqrt{1+ \left(\frac{l}{\rho}\right)^2} \right| = \frac1{4\pi } \log\rho + \log\left|l + \sqrt{\rho^2+l^2}\right|$$
which gives
$\frac1{2\pi} \log \rho + 2\log l + 2\log\left|1 + \sqrt{1+\rho^2/l^2}\right|$
which is at least correct up to $\log l + o(1)$... (don't know what to do with this)

Comment: @Ian Interesant, and $\Phi = \frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\rho + \text{constant}$ is solution. Regardless of whether $l$ goes to infinity, the Laplacian will be the same. Thanks, it's enough for me, but i have a doubt, where is the rigor?

Comment: @CalvinKhor The $\ln{l}+\ln\left|1+\sqrt{1+\rho^2/l^2}\right|$ is a constant I think where $l\to\infty$, the important is $\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln\rho$. This help me to convince me, thank you.

Comment: @Elborito you're welcome, I thought about it for quite a long time to see if I could make it rigourous by using a renormalised distribution, but I'm not sure how to do it.... (also its missing a minus sign on $\ln l$ and it should be $O(1)$ and not $o(1)$, sorry)

Comment: Note that what I wrote still needs $l \to \infty$ to make the asymptotics work.